# Default value for missing parameter in a Camel route

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I have an application that uses Apache Camel with Active MQ. In my `RouteBuilder` class where I configure the routes, it is possible that a parameter may be missing from the `in` body. In that case, I would like to give it a default value.

Here is what I have now:

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    ...

    String invocation = "aMethod( ${body[context]},  ${body[aParam]}, ${body[param2]} )";

    from(url).routeId(url).bean(bean, invocation);
}
```

In my case, `param2` is a boolean which I would like to send forward to `aMethod` as `false` in case it doesn't exist. How can I do that?

I saw something here: http://camel.apache.org/simple.html#Simple-OGNLexpressionsupport where it says *"You can also use the null safe operator (?.) to avoid NPE if for example the body does NOT have an address"*, but I can't figure how to write the invocation so I don't have an error in the specified case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking to use a conditional similar to this:

```
from("")
   .choice()
       .when(header("myHeader").isNull())
           .setHeader("myHeader").simple("false")
    .end()  //This might be endChoice can't remember syntax exactly
    .bean(myBean, myMethod);
```

..revised for Object in the body

```
from("")
    .processor( new Processor(Exchange exchange) {
        MyObject obj = exchange.getIn().getBody(MyObject.class);
        Boolean b = obj.getParam2();
        if(b == null)
             obj.setParam2(Boolean.FALSE);
    }
    .bean(myBean, myMethod);
```

NOTE:  If your actual java class uses 'boolean' and not the 'Boolean' class wrapper, then all booleans when initialized are by default set to false.  So if you have an object in your body and nobody has the the boolean it will default to false.

Comment: So in my case I should write like this?
    choice().when(header("${body[param2]}").isNull())
        .setHeader("${body[param2]}").simple("false")
    .end()

Comment: ok I see you want to use getters and setters on an object in the body.  ok that makes sense let me revise my answer for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't set the default value as I wanted, as I don't know what exactly is that `body` in my code. But your processor example helped me to find the methods that didn't have that parameter.